# I cannot add local css to thymeleaf - but adding bootstrap and jquery works

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[Error Message From Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfPF7.png)

[The Folder Structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg7CW.png)

[How I linked this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYUWl.png)

So I am trying to Link local css file to thymeleaf but it has not been working. I was wondering how to link css to thymeleaf in this case. Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `href="@{/css/signup.css}"`, but you need to use `th:href` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/signup.css}" />
```

Comment: Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.